# Why do I get White label error page type=Method Not Allowed, status=405 for delete operation?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I have java springboot as backend and angular as front for CRUD operations. Only delete operation is not working at all. I get the error in eclipse log javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:295 and the postman shows status 405, Method not allowed error.
Here are my codes: Service

```
       @Service

public class EmployeeService {
    private final EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService (EmployeeRepo employeeRepo) {
        this.employeeRepo = employeeRepo;
    }
    public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employee.setEmployeeCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return employeeRepo.save(employee);
    }
    public List<Employee> findAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepo.findAll();
    }
    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepo.save(employee);
    }
    public Employee findEmployeeById(Long id) {
        return employeeRepo.findEmployeeById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User by id " + id + "was not found"));
    }
    public void deleteEmployee(Long id) {
        employeeRepo.deleteEmployeeById(id);
        
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeResource {
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    public EmployeeResource(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllEmployees();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.findEmployeeById(id); 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        Employee newEmployee = employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newEmployee, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        Employee updateEmployee = employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updateEmployee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


Springboot Application:
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmployeemanagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeemanagerApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Access", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type","Accept", "Authorization", 
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }

}
```

application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/employeemanager?useSSL\=false
server.port=8060
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I followed suggestions from other posts to use annotation `Transactional` at

```
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Transactional
    void deleteEmployeeById(Long id);
```

and that works!